# Checkstyle working in Maven, but not working in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, jenkins-plugins, checkstyle

I am using Maven, Maven checkstyle plugin, Jenkins and Jenkins checkstyle plugin.

I have 7 projects total. 1 parent and 6 child projects.

I have the following 3 scenarios :

1. Checkstyle report for all project.n parent pom i declared checkstyle plugin in  tag:

   - I run `mvn clean site` command
   - It working both ways in eclipse with maven. and in Jenkins also.
   - Giving checkstyle reports for all 7 projects.
2. Checkstyle report for all project except 2 project.

   - I deleted  part in parent pom and i added
   - I added in remaining 4 projects, i declared checkstyle plugin in  tag.
   - It working in eclipse but not working in Jenkins.

   Please give solution

   My code:

   ```
   <reporting>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.10</version>
           <configuration>
               <configLocation>../parent-project/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
   ```

3.

- I deleted checkstyle plugin in parent
- I added checkstyle plugin in 4 needed projects same above code.
- In remaining 2 child projects I added like this.

  ```
  <reporting>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.10</version>
          <configuration>
              <skip>true</skip>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
  ```
- I run 'mvn clean site'
- It working in Maven as expected but not working in Jenkins.

What I mean by 'not working in Jenkins' is that I installed checkstyle plugin in Jenkins, In the Jenkins job i selected 'Publish Checkstyle analysis results' check box. In scenario-1 i am able to see the checkstyle link in the jenkins job page. And if i click on that all code violations reports are appearing. In other scenarios (2,3) the Checkstyle link also not appearing.

Comment: I have the exact same issue myself right now. I hope someone will give an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Just found the solution.

In the project configure menu, in the "Goals and options" field you need to add 'site' without the ' characters. In my "Goals and options" field I had: clean install. This did not run checkstyle. But then I changed it to: clean install site. And now checkstyle runs!

Hope this solves your problem.

Edit:

My pom.xml has been extended with the tag:

```
<reporting>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

to run checkstyle. Try using only that for checkstyle and then run the project again.

Comment: Sorry, I did same(clean install site) but no result. can you please provide some more details.